# Does AWS Lambda Encrypt In-Flight Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda

I originally asked this question here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=769734#769734

However I haven't seen any activity on it of any kind I hope I have more success here.

**Do my requests going to and coming from Lambda functions get encrypted? Basically my json input that is passed to the Lambda event, should I worry about this information being sent as plain text?**

Main Purpose:

EC2 instances are the main ones that will be calling this function. However, this lambda does not reside in the same VPC as the instance. The lambda will be returning data as part of a "[RequestResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html)" call. The return of the lambda will be stored on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where your requests are coming from and going to? For example, what is triggering your Lambda functions? Is it coming from outside of AWS, or being triggered by an activity on AWS (eg uploading a file to Amazon S3)? Also, what do you mean by "coming from" Lambda -- are you using a return value from the function?

Comment: I have updated my question to include answers to  your question.

Comment: How are you calling the Lambda functions? Are they via API calls that use the AWS SDK? If so, such calls are made via HTTPS requests, so they are encrypted in flight.

Comment: Excellent! I am using the aws cli with the following example: aws lambda invoke --function-name <my_function_name> --invocation-type RequestResponse --payload '{JSON}' --region <my_region> json <output>. According to your response as long as I use the CLI from anywhere (Whether my local machine or an ec2 instance) my in-flight requests will all be encrypted via https. This is what I was hopping. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are triggering AWS Lambda functions via AWS API calls, then the requests are send to a HTTPS endpoint.

See: [AWS Lambda Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#lambda_region) (Notice that protocol is `HTTPS`)

HTTPS encrypts your request and the response, so your data is encrypted in transit.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is a Python app that uses the AWS SDK for Python (`boto3`) that in-turn calls the AWS API endpoints, so requests from the AWS CLI are also encrypted.

Comment: What about via AWS SDK call? From this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html), the **Invoke** call generates a POST using HTTP/1.1. Is there a way to set it to HTTPS?

Comment: @SimonSays The [endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html) protocols are HTTPS.